# Omit last page on NUMPAGES Aspose .net

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

I'm looking for a solution in ASPOSE .Net to decrement the NUMPAGES. Reason is that I don't want to count the last page of the document. Here is what I tried so far:

```
builder.Write("Page ");
builder.InsertField("Page", "");
builder.Write(" of ");
builder.InsertField("NUMPAGES", $"{(doc.PageCount - 1)}");

// Another try in separate build
builder.InsertField("NUMPAGES - 1", "");

// Another try in separate build
builder.InsertField("NUMPAGES", "NUMPAGES - 1");
```

Document either doesn't display anything or count the last page as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use formula and nested NUMPAGES field to get the desired output. Field code in your MS Word document should look like this:
`{={NUMPAGES}-1}`. To insert such field using Aspose.Words you can use code like this:

```cs
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Insert formula field
Field formula = builder.InsertField("=", "");
// Move document builder inside field code of the inserted field
// And put NUMPAGES field in it.
builder.MoveTo(formula.Separator);
builder.InsertField("NUMPAGES");
builder.Write("-1");

doc.UpdateFields();
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

Please see Aspose.Words documentation to learn [how to work with fields](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/working-with-fields/).